# Why it this printing "none" after running program?

Tags: python

```
class student:
    def name(self):
        print('Aman')
        print('kant')
class hostel_fee(student):
    def hfee(self):
        print('hostel fee',int(78000))
        return 78000
class academic_fee(student):
    def afee(self,):
        print('academic fee',int(69500))
        return 69500*2
class total_fee(hostel_fee,academic_fee):
    def Total(self):
        self.h=super().hfee()
        self.a=super().afee()
        self.t=self.a+self.h
        print('total fee',self.t)
        print(super().name())
obj=total_fee()
obj.Total()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `print(super().name())` in `class total_fee`, that in turn calls on `student` via the tree of inheritance, but this method returns nothing (`None`)